# When one polynomial be a power of another polynomial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, invariant-theory

Let consider two polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ with rational coefficients such that the degree of $f$ is divisible by the degree of $g$: $\deg f(x) = k \cdot \deg g(x)$, where $k$ is a natural number.
What is the criterion for the polynomial $f$ to be a power of the polynomial $g(x)$, that is, when the equality $f(x) = (g(x))^k$ up to constant factor holds?

One approach is to find the resultants of all derivatives of $f$ and $g$: $$Res(f, g), Res(f', g), Res(f'', g), \ldots, Res(f^{(k-1)}, g).$$ If they are all equal to zero, then $f(x) = C (g(x))^k$, $C$ is a constant factor.
But this is a long complicated  method; is there a simpler way?

**P.S**. The polynomial $f$ is a linear combination of the known polynomials $f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_n$. I need to find such coefficients $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n$ that $$f = \alpha_1 f_1 + \alpha_2 f_2 + \ldots + \alpha_n f_n = C \cdot (g(x))^k $$ Therefore, I cannot directly verify that $f(x) = C \cdot (g(x))^k$.

**P.S.2** I have the folynomials $f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_n, g $ over $\mathbb{Q}$, $\deg f_1=\deg f_2 = \cdots = \deg f_n$.  How can I decide if there are scalars $\alpha_i$ such that the  linear combination of $f_i$  is a power of $g$  up to constant factor
$$
f= \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i f_i=C \cdot (g(x))^{\frac{\deg f}{\deg g}}?
$$

Comment: I suppose you could raise $g(x)$ to the power $\deg f(x)/\deg g(x)$ and see if you get $f(x)$.

Comment: I cannot do this because I do not have the explicit form of the polynomial $f$; I need a general criterion.

Comment: Then the question should explicitly list everything that you know about $f$ and $g$.

Comment: I have made some clarifications to my question, please take a look at them.

Comment: Because the question, after all the clarifications, has been modified and changed its form.

Comment: Surely the answer depends on $n$. If $n>\deg f$ then the space of possible linear combinations (at least generically) consists of the entire space of polynomials of degree $n$, making the question rather trivial. Anyway, for fixed choices of $m=\deg g$ and $\ell=\deg f$ we can view the process of raising a polynomial to power $\ell/m$ as a morphism of projective spaces $\phi:\Bbb{P}^m\to\Bbb{P}^\ell$. It should be possible (but I don't know it right away except when $m=1$) to determinen a system of equations describing the image, call it $V$ (IIRC guaranteed to be a subvariety).

Comment: (cont'd) Then you need to determine whether the linear span of the $f_i$ intersect with $V$. IIRC guaranteed to happen over $\Bbb{C}$ if the dimensions are high enough.
Of course, if the degree of $g$ is not known, then you need to this for several varieties. I'm afraid I cannot tell how heavy this would be computationally. Or, is at all helpful in your situation.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen I thought this was a well-known problem that had already been solved.

Comment: It may well be known (in one form or another). There is a reason why I only made a comment as opposed to an answer :-)